# What's the difference between "parent" and "category_parent" in a WP_Term object?

Tags: categories, taxonomy

What's the difference between "parent" and "category_parent" in a WP_Term object? For example:

```
[1] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 24
        [name] => Essential Oils
        [slug] => essential-oils
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 24
        [taxonomy] => category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 22
        [count] => 14
        [filter] => raw
        [cat_ID] => 24
        [category_count] => 14
        [category_description] => 
        [cat_name] => Essential Oils
        [category_nicename] => essential-oils
        [category_parent] => 22
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties prefixed with `category_` or `cat_` are there for backwards compatibility.

Taxonomies and terms were [introduced in WordPress 2.3](https://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Version_2.3:New_Taxonomy) (11 years ago) and categories were converted into a taxonomy at that time. Prior to this categories had their own properties (the ones with the aforementioned prefixes).

For backwards compatibility, the `_make_cat_compat()` function is used in some places to add the old properties to categories. You can see from [the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_make_cat_compat/) that all it does is copy the standard term properties to the old names, so `parent` and `category_parent` will always have the same value, as an example.

In 2018 you should avoid using the category-specific properties.